# Create then retrieve document via query with WHERE clause in a CosmosDB stored procedure

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

In a stored procedure, I found that running `collection.queryDocuments(...)` with a `WHERE` clause will not return documents that were previously created in the same execution. Is that expected and is there any way around this?

For example, take this simplified stored procedure:

```
function createThenQuery() {
    const collection = getContext().getCollection();
    const collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
    const response = getContext().getResponse();
    const document = { name: "Some Name" };

    collection.createDocument(collectionLink, document, (err, createdDocument) => {
        const query = `SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.name='${document.name}'`;
        collection.queryDocuments(collectionLink, query, {}, (err, retrievedDocs) => {
            console.log(retrievedDocs.length);
        });
    });
}
```

This outputs the following:

```
1st run: 0
2nd run: 1
3rd run: 2
etc...
```

However, when I remove the `WHERE` clause (`SELECT * FROM c`) it outputs the following:

```
1st run: 1
2nd run: 2
3rd run: 3
etc...
```

I would expect this second output in both scenarios. Is there any way I could fix this so it returns what I expect when using a `WHERE` clause?

I'm guessing this is maybe because some index isn't being updated until the stored procedure has finished running and the transaction is committed? Perhaps there's a way to disable that or force an update? In this case it's a one time script so it's ok if it runs a little slower.

Right now I'm settling for maintaining a separate array of created documents that I search through in addition to also searching the documents in the collection. That's not ideal though because it adds some complexity.

Comment: I encountered the similar issue as you mentioned, though the indexing mode of my single-partition collection is set to **consistent** which means that the index should be updated synchronously as part of the document update (insert, replace, update, and delete a document under a collection).

Comment: @BruceChen hmmm I just looked into what the collection's indexing mode is and it's also set to consistent. I was thinking that this might relate to the [consistency level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/consistency-levels) specified when querying, but I haven't found a way to set that to `Strong` in a stored procedure to try it out (only in c# there's a `ConsistencyLevel` on `RequestOptions`). It seems like `Strong` is the default though...

Comment: I followed the link you provide and read the section about [consistency-levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/consistency-levels#consistency-levels) which states that `you can configure a default consistency level on your database account that applies to all collections (and databases) under your Cosmos DB account. By default, all reads and queries issued against the user-defined resources use the default consistency level specified on the database account. `Also you could set the consistency level for a specific read/query request.

Comment: I logged into azure portal and click "SETTINGS > Default consistency" of my Cosmos DB account, then I found that the default consistency level for my database account is SESSION. I also tried to change it to STRONG level, then execute my SP on Azure Portal, but without luck in the end.